# Printing the value of a float to 2 decimal places

Tags: c++, winapi, floating-point, format, printf

I have a float with the value of e.g 57.400002. I use `sprintf_s` to display the value on my GUI.

```
sprintf_s(xPosition, 19, "%f", xPositionValue);
```

How can I format the float so it displays as 57.40?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sprintf_s(xPosition, 19, "%.2f", xPositionValue);`

Answer (score 8):

```
sprintf_s(xPosition, 19, "%.2f", xPositionValue);
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/ for more documentation on format codes.

Answer (score 3):

```
sprintf_s(xPosition, 19, "%.2f", xPositionValue);
```

should do the trick doesn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the width and precision tags, just like printf

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

I think you would want the following:

sprintf_s(xPosition, 19, "%.2f", xPositionValue);